# Is there a way to save [[Promise Result]] as a variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to access [[Promise Results]] and save it as a variable. The end goal I just want the result from the .then statement and use it in other function. If there is another better way to do it please let me, I'm new to JavaScript, so it would be awesome if you could explain it to me than just dump code. Thanks is advance
Here is the fetch request

```
function currentloginid() {
    return fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid', {
       method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        var userid = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(userid);
        return userid;
    })
}
```

The code below is when I console log the function in another function

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: 1
```

Comment: `let variable = currentloginid();` ... now variable is the promise

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok cool, I want to save the [[]PromiseResult]] value. Not the whole promise

Comment: `let variable = await currentloginid()` in an `async` function

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm receiving and error await is only valid in async function, do add async to the function calling it or to currentloginid?

Comment: as I said that works `in an async function`

Comment: `response.json()` promise resolves with parsed object. No need for JSON.parse()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 3 ways for solving this:

1. Since you return a promise, use `.then` to get the returned value.

```js
function currentloginid() {
  return fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      var userid = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(userid);
      return userid;
    })
}

currentloginid().then(value => console.log(value));
```

2. In one of the `.then` you already have, set an outside variable to the value. However this solution is not good since you could encounter situation where `myValue` is not set.

```js
let myValue;

function currentloginid() {
  return fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      var userid = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(userid);
      myValue = userid
      return userid;
    })
}

currentloginid();
console.log(myValue);
```

3. Use the syntactic sugar `async await` to "await" for the value to return. I think that this approach is much more readable and easy to use (behind the scenes it's the same as option 1).

```
function currentloginid() {
  return fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      var userid = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(userid);
      return userid;
    })
}

console.log(await currentloginid());
```

Comment: Thank you!, you provided me with options of how to solve this problem which is great, and gave a brief explanation on how each of them worked, it help a lot thank you :)

Comment: This explanation is great! I now grasp the concept of fetch way better!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of promise chains you could use `async/await` and return the data(userid) directly.

```
const currentloginid = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost/gaq/api/api.php?action=userid')

  const data = await response.json()
  
  //console.log(JSON.parse(data))

  return JSON.parse(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call then() on the same promise as many times as you want.

Storing the promise returned by the function in a variable allows you to use `then()` on that variable whenever you need to

```js
function currentloginid() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
}

const storedPromise = currentloginid();
console.log('No delay')
storedPromise.then(({name, id})=> console.log({name, id}))

setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log('After delay, same promise')
  storedPromise.then(({name, id})=> console.log({name, id}))
}, 2000)
```

Comment: You may need to use the "useState" and update the state in the chain.

Comment: @aminamin There is no React involved here