# Returning [object Promise] instead of actual value

Tags: javascript, promise

I am new to promises as I am trying to get some objects to show there actual values on a webpage. Instead I am just getting a bunch of `[object Promise]` instead

This is the code I have so far:

```
\\ This section fetches the api results and puts them into a list/array 
async function getitglinkquery(){
    
    var linkresults = await parseitgsearchquery();
    console.log(linkresults);
    // var linkresultvalues = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < linkresults.length; i++) {
    var linkresultvalues = fetch(linkresults[i], {
        method: "GET",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            // needed to base64 encode my key with ":x" at the end of the api key then I used that for the authorization header.
        "x-api-key": "INSERTAPITHINGYHERE"}})
        .then(response => response.json())
        
        }
    return linkresultvalues;
}

\\**This section is trying to get the promise and parse the results**
async function parseitglinkquery() {
    var queriedresults = await getitglinkquery();
    console.log(typeof queriedresults);
    // linkresultvalues.push(response);
    const output = document.querySelector('span.ms-font-mitglue');
    let pre = document.createElement('p');
    
    pre.innerHTML = queriedresults;
    pre.style.cssText += 'font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;';

    output.appendChild(pre);
    
}
parseitglinkquery();
}
```

**What I tried**

I tried reading the firefox `promise.resolve` method as that seems like what I was looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve However I tried using the static promise.resolve method example they have and it didn't work for me. Like so:

```
\\ This section is trying to get the promise and parse the results
async function parseitglinkquery() {
    var queriedresults = await Promise.resolve(getitglinkquery());
    console.log(queriedresults);  \\ This is where my promises are coming out of
}
```

So I don't think that is what I am looking for. I also tried reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64165144 but I don't know how to use the `.then` method to get the variables from the result. I already put `.then` in the api request at the first function yet I still have a list of promises.

Picture of the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzPOj.png)

Picture of the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2FOk.png)

I tried `Promise.all()` but it errored out and didn't work so I don't think that is the issue as well. I double checked my `queriedresults` variable to make sure its an object by using console.log(typeof queriedresults) and it said it was an object.

Attempted code:

```
async function parseitglinkquery() {
    var queriedresults = await Promise.all(getitglinkquery());
}
```

Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Picture of the failure again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhF3h.png)

I tried using:

```
queriedresults.then(function(result){
        console.log(result)
        
    })
```

based on the information from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516570/16660683
but that didn't work either as I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: queriedresults.then is not a function

Comment: Take a look at `Promise.all()`, if you have an array of promises it's most likely what you're looking for. Also, try to avoid mixing promises with await, it makes it hard to reason about the code.

Comment: You pasted poorly or your code has some seriously unbalanced `(` and `{`.

Comment: @MichałSadowski I found out that my promise isn't an array. it just looks like one because I made a variable called `linkresultvaluesx` and put my fetch into that instead. Then I appended all the results of the fetch like so: `linkresultvalues.push(linkresultvaluesx)`. I only assume its not an array because when I tried `var querriedresults = await Promise.all(getitglinkquerry());` I got an error that said `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not iterable ` I am going to try to see the type of data it is by using console.log(typeof querriedresults)). Be back soon

Comment: @stsitilegnikcuferasyuguoy You need to put the `return Promise.all(linkresultvalues);` *inside* the `getitglinkquerry` function. The call shouldn't change. (Btw, I'd recommend renaming `linkresultvalues` to `linkresultpromises` since it's an array of promises)

Comment: @bergi I am pretty sure you just hit the nail on the head. I am gettting [object Object] instead but I think I can retrieve that object data by iterating over what I want in a for loop. so I think this solve the main issue of how to get my results from a promise. If you make an answer to this I will give you credit. Also I will probably change the variable to `linkresultpromises` instead. The wording is better and more on topic. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper usage of `Promise.all` is

```
async function getItglinkQuery() {
    const linkresultUrls = await parseItgsearchQuery();
    const linkresultPromises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < linkresults.length; i++) {
        const promise = fetch(linkresults[i], {
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
               "x-api-key": "INSERTAPITHINGYHERE"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json());
        
        linkresultPromises.push(promise);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    return Promise.all(linkresultPromises);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Now, `getItglinkQuery` returns a promise for an array of values, not a promise for an array of promises.

Comment: I am too low to give you an +1 but I marked yours as the answer. 

Because of you I was able to continue onto parsing the actual object instead of getting promises. Now everything on the webpage works perfectly. Thank you again.